Problem retrieving lexemes via sparql query on local wikibase installation
I recently installed wikibase locally on my machine in Docker (following instructions on MediaWiki:https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Docker), and I believe I was able to install the WikibaseLexemes extension successfully. I installed MediaWiki version 1.40 on Mac with WikibaseLexemes version 1.40.
Immediately afterward, however, I created some lexemes and a standard sparql query for lexemes such as the one below does not return anything. I know the lexemes exist because I can retrieve individual lexemes by manual search on the front page or on Special Pages:Recent Changes.
Has anyone encountered this issue before, or know how to diagnose and fix it?
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX ontolex: <http://www.w3.org/ns/lemon/ontolex#>
SELECT DISTINCT
  ?lexeme
WHERE {
    ?lexeme a ontolex:LexicalEntry .
           
}

I believe I made all the necessary modifications to the LocalSettings.php file to get the WikibaseLexemes extension to work properly. No blatant errors appear in the log files of any of the docker containers.
The above sparql query should return all the lexemes I created, but it returns nothing. I know it is not a general sparql query problem because a query that returns all items and properties functions correctly. Even a query that recalls all possible triples of the wikibase skips over lexemes, which is wrong.
